# javax.crypto is subject to export controls; what does that mean?

Tags: java, security

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/overview/jsoverview.html:

> For historical (export control) reasons, the cryptography APIs
>   are organized into two distinct packages. The
>   `java.security` package contains classes that are
>   *not* subject to export controls (like `Signature`
>   and `MessageDigest`). The `javax.crypto`
>   package contains classes that are subject to export controls (like
>   `Cipher` and `KeyAgreement`).

What does this mean?   
What is the difference?

**Note:** This document reference is quoted in Java EE doc in security section >> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbwj.html | is this ref outdated ?

Comment: Shouldn't your question title be something like "What are export controls in reference to Java security packages?"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_in_the_United_States

Comment: @supersam654, are you the one who did down vote ? If not then do down voters agree with your Q ?

Comment: Where did you read that? The Javadoc for those classes doesn't say anything about export controls, even in 1.4. Cryptographic export controls were dropped during the Clinton administration.

Comment: @EJP, here you go >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/overview/jsoverview.html

Comment: @RaviTrivedi: That's not Javadoc (nor even "Java Doc").

Comment: @ruakh, what should I call it then ?

Comment: @RaviTrived Not only is it not Javadoc, it also answers your question, to the extent that there is one. But it's obsolete.

Comment: @EJP, pleases check updated answer.

Comment: @EJP, well, it says in the heading "java Documentation". What should I call it then ? :)

Comment: Err, 'Java Documentation'? Javadoc is the stuff produced by the 'javadoc' tool.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, create an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: A mere link is not an answer here.

Comment: I agree. It's perfectly clear that you don't know what constitutes an answer, but you've already had one. An answer contains text that addresses the question being asked.

Comment: I perfectly know what consists an answer to this question. What consists an answer in SO, according to you ?

Comment: @RaviTrivedi - [this somewhat old excerpt](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170967&seqNum=14) explains the requirement quite nicely.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I've already answered that, and it isn't just 'according to me'. NB the person who asks the question is usually the worst judge of what am answer is, by definition.

Answer (score 7):

The first thing to note is that the text you quoted starts 'for historic reasons'.

The USA had export controls over some cryptographic algorithms and implementations above certain key lengths. They were mostly dropped during the Clinton administration: certainly those that affected Java. Any reference you read to them in reference to Java cryptography is obsolete.

Java is however affected by crypto *import* policies, and that's why the Unlimited Strength Crypto Policy download exists. If it's legal in your jurisdiction, you can download and install it. All it does is enable code that is already present in the JRE and which therefore has already been exported. QED

Comment: please check updated answer. Java EE doc security section has this reference.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. It's obsolete. You can produce as many other references as you like: it doesn't change anything. The cryptography export controls were dropped last century. That's the answer to your question.

Comment: Can you provide the reference to what you are saying ? Thanks,

Comment: It's in Wikipedia, for a start.

Comment: export control still exists. Read "Current Status" section.

Comment: Please stop this. Don't misquote me and then ask me what the misquote means. The remainder of your comment is completely devoid of meaning. Your question has been answered.